# Play services 9.+ don't install wear app

Tags: wear-os

I have an application with a wear and a handheld side.

**Before the update:**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'
```

**After the update:**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
```

When I've updated the gradle with the last google play services version the application is not installed on the watch anymore. Does anyone know if there is a different requirement to automate the process of installing the application on the watch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The watch app only gets installed if the watch has the required Google play services.

This changed recently. Maybe 9.0 or maybe it's android wear 1.5 doing the check. it used to install no matter the version before.

This is a common problem at the moment, a few users having trouble updateing their watches to greater than 9.0. there's even a g+ post on the android wear developer community asking for bug reports to help fix the problem.

Comment: The issue reported on that question is not the same because on my watch the google play services are up to date (9.2.56)! The wear app is just not installed...